# The integral of an infinite sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

For the integral:

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{4}}dx$

How does one go about calculating this?

I've only learned how to do U-substitution, and I lack the knowledge to somehow integrate an infinite sum.

Comment: Request for clarification (and also possibly a minor hint?): what does $\sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$ actually mean when $n$ is not an integer? Are we simply summing from $\lceil x \rceil$ (i.e. the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$) to $\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the summation notation is as I guessed in the comments, then notice that the integrand is constant on intervals of the form $(m, m + 1]$ where $m \in \Bbb{N}$. So, in particular, we can write,
$$\int_1^\infty \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \int_m^{m+1}\sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}.$$
We can then change the order of summation to yield
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} &= \frac{1}{2^4} + \left(\frac{1}{3^4} + \frac{1}{3^4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4^4} + \frac{1}{4^4} + \frac{1}{4^4}\right) + \ldots \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n^4} \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4} \\
&= \zeta(3)-\zeta(4).
\end{align*}